# firebird trigger string concatenation

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird, string-concatenation

anyone can help me with this. I created a trigger in firebird. I have this line that uses concatenation.

```
NEW.FIELDNAME = FIELD1 || FIELD2;
```

but it is not working, no record has been inserted. Is there any way for string concatenation? THANKS IN ADVANCE!

here is my full trigger

*query that initiate the variable PREV_STATUS:

```
SELECT FIRST 1 PREV_STATUSPERMINS FROM C3_EQUIPTSTATEPERMIN
     WHERE TESTERID = NEW.TESTERID ORDER BY DATEMODIFIED DESC INTO :PREV_STATUS;


IF(PREV_STATUS IS NULL) THEN
  BEGIN
    NEW.PREV_STATUSPERMINS = '000';
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    NEW.PREV_STATUSPERMINS = PREV_STATUS || NEW.STATUS;
  END
```

Comment: Although I think the [answer by jonneve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24503878/466862) is sufficient, could you please include the full trigger code (or at least the trigger header) and the origin of `FIELD1` and `FIELD2` and their values.

Comment: What type of trigger is it? You didn't include the trigger header in your edit. BTW: What table is the trigger defined on? If it is `C3_EQUIPTSTATEPERMIN` then you shouldn't select from it in the trigger, but use the `OLD` context variables instead

Answer (score 4):

You should use the "new" keyword to access the values of your fields within a trigger :

```
new.fieldname = new.field1 || new.field2;
```

Also, don't forget that if either of the fields is null, the concatenation will be null. If you want to avoid that, you could do something like this :

```
NEW.FIELDNAME = coalesce(new.FIELD1, '') || coalesce(new.FIELD2, '')
```

Comment: oh im sorry. I already included the word 'NEW'. Please see my updates

Comment: In your code above, the new.status field may very well be null, in which case it would cause NEW.PREV_STATUSPERMINS to be null too.